# Participle phrase order in the sentence

Tags: syntax, past-participles

In the phrase below, the last participle phrase looks attached to "pets" or rather to "cats and dogs".

What would be your first opinion?

Sam liked pets, including cats and dogs, encountered in the street.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. *including cats and dogs* is bracketed by commas and is therefore understood as a parenthesis; consequently, *encountered ...* is understood to modify *pets*.

Answer (score 1):

“Including cats and dogs” is bracketed by commas and is therefore understood as a parenthesis.

Consequently, “encountered [. . .]” is understood to modify “pets”.